# Ubuntu 22.04.1 Rebooting after switch to sleep mode

Tags: suspend, reboot

Recently I upgraded from 20.04LTS to 22.04.1LTS. Upgrade was smooth, but since then my laptop is rebooting in sleep mode. Normally I just close the lid when I finish work and open it when I start and have all open software, files and folder as they were. Previously it worked fine, but since upgrade system reboots randomly (not always, I haven't found a key yet) and when I open lid there's clear system after reboot, and my work is gone.
I searched through power management questions but noone asked about problem similar to mine. Do you have any solution for this behaviour?

Comment: I have the same problem - permanent reboot after sleep or hibernate. Let's try to find the solution togeter!

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the mem_sleep param in sysfs, maybe you may switch sleep mode.

I had **deep** mode by default, after switching to **s2idle** my laptop started to work as expected:

```
# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
s2idle [deep]
# echo "s2idle" > /sys/power/mem_sleep 
# cat /sys/power/mem_sleep 
[s2idle] deep
```

Current behavior of deep sleep looks like an Ubuntu issue, I'll try to report it.

Comment: I get "Permission denied" running the echo command (both sudo and non sudo). Any tips on this?

Comment: Yeah, you need to run all commands under root user. Please do 
`sudo bash` before executing commands above.

Comment: I solved my problem by switching to a Nvidia proprietary video driver. Previously the Noveau drivers were selected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried a lot of things (editing the logind.conf etc.). A **complete shutdown** (instead of reboot) solved my problem.